# If self-control is the executive function to resist temptation, how does the brain decide what is and what is not a temptation?

Tags: behavior, willpower

What determines the "default behaviour" if no self-control is applied?

Most documents refer to satisfaction of immediate desire, but that does not seem to explain how quite sophisticated behaviors can occur as the result of a failure of self-control. A temptation to eat fast food which involves purchasing it, or to consume internet pornography, can require higher or executive functions to satisfy in terms of computer operation and engagement with a purchasing process. A temptation to take illegal drugs can potentially require delaying gratification for an unknown period of time (to find a supplier).

So is there research on what determines the behavior without self-control, and how it is able to "hijack" executive functions that should rightfully be limiting the undesirable behavior?

Comment: Interesting question! It's not all black and white if one considers "cortico-cortical loops" between the cortex and the subcortex. I had to be reminded of that by others in my question here: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/23119/can-signals-from-the-prefrontal-cortex-alone-trigger-a-readiness-potential-in-th

Comment: In your particular question, one probably needs to distinguish between subjects who express different levels of executive-motivational conflict. To what extent does the individual in question want to prevent the "default behavior"?

Comment: I think you might be mixing different types of [executive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_functions) - you should think of it as not one concept but rather a collection of concepts, which are potentially associated with some non-overlapping brain areas (though studying some of them independently is a challenge). Also, "A temptation to take illegal drugs can potentially require delaying gratification for an unknown period of time" is a very poor example of self-control: it's really quite the opposite, because the delay is externally rather than internally imposed.

Comment: It's more what the definition of temptation is. For example, if an individual has to choose between two covered platters (which secretly hold, let's say, a cookie and a radish), what is the smallest amount of information necessary for this choice to become a matter of willpower?

Comment: I suppose executive function originates from somewhere in the brain so it is never a matter of will-power. Temptations I would say are more about lower-level(physical?) needs. The only valuable research in this area for me is studying ways to increase your capacity for making decisions at higher level of consciousness.